# How to do target_link_libraries in CMake without actual linking?

Tags: cmake, dependency-management, pkg-config

Now, I know how the question sounds... however, [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/target_link_libraries.html) does more than just linking. And I want this "more" but not the linking. How to do it?

My current setup looks (in a simplified view) like this:

[image: CMake targets and their relations]

The "3rd Party" target is a [PkgConfig](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/module/FindPkgConfig.html) created target. The rest is my own.

However, this setup creates a problem in tests. In "Application UTs" I don't want to use the "3rd Party" library. I want to use its stub. To put it in a picture, I would like to have the following instead:

[image: Desired CMake setup]

The dotted lines are "something" - it could be targets dependency (to avoid repeating the same information, like include paths), however, I consider it an implementation detail as long as it works.

If I would be in control of the "3rd Party" targets I would just do them like that. But I'm not. I'm receiving `.pc` files and I have the target created by [PkgConfig](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/module/FindPkgConfig.html). While the created target is this single target having it all.

For now, I have solved it by creating a custom function `target_nonlink_libraries` which propagates the following target properties:

- [`INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html),
- [`INTERFACE_COMPILE_FEATURES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_COMPILE_FEATURES.html),
- [`INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS.html),
- [`INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html),
- [`INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html).

(Note, that this does not include all [`INTERFACE_...`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/manual/cmake-properties.7.html) properties.)

The code looks like this:

```
function(target_nonlink_libraries TARGET_NAME SCOPE SOURCE_TARGET)
    foreach(source_target IN ITEMS ${SOURCE_TARGET} ${ARGN})
        get_target_property(interface_compile_definitions ${source_target} INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)
        if(interface_compile_definitions)
            target_compile_definitions(${TARGET_NAME}
                ${SCOPE}
                    ${interface_compile_definitions}
            )
        endif()

        get_target_property(interface_compile_features ${source_target} INTERFACE_COMPILE_FEATURES)
        if(interface_compile_features)
            target_compile_definitions(${TARGET_NAME}
                ${SCOPE}
                    ${interface_compile_features}
            )
        endif()

        get_target_property(interface_compile_options ${source_target} INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS)
        if(interface_compile_options)
            target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME}
                ${SCOPE}
                    ${interface_compile_options}
            )
        endif()

        get_target_property(interface_include_directories ${source_target} INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
        if(interface_include_directories)
            target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME}
                ${SCOPE}
                    ${interface_include_directories}
            )
        endif()

        get_target_property(interface_system_include_directories ${source_target} INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
        if(interface_system_include_directories)
            target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME} SYSTEM
                ${SCOPE}
                    ${interface_system_include_directories}
            )
        endif()
    endforeach()
endfunction()
```

and is later used like this:

```
target_nonlink_libraries(ApplicationCommon
    INTERFACE
        PkgConfig::Library
)
target_link_libraries(Application
    PRIVATE
        PkgConfig::Library
)
```

The problem here, however, is that I'm not sure that I'm copying all properties (which I care about) and doing it in the correct way.

How to solve this in CMake? Is there any build-in to link targets explicitly skipping actual linking?

Comment: Perhaps this approach doesn't work leading to linking issues in some scenarios as explained in https://discourse.cmake.org/t/how-to-do-link-time-polymorphism-right/3381.